# The below sql code shows the error : ORA-01727: numeric precision specifier is out of range (1 to 38)

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, sqldatatypes

This SQL code results in an error :

> ORA-01727: numeric precision specifier is out of range (1 to 38).

What changes should be made for the code to work?

```
CREATE TABLE employees 
(
    e_id NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    f_name VARCHAR(20),
    salary NUMBER(50),
    dept_name VARCHAR(10)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/olap.102/b14346/dml_datatypes002.htm), the `NUMBER` type has a range of up to 38 significant figures:

> A decimal number with up to 38 significant digits in the range of -(10^125) to +(10^125).

You may decrease the precision of your `salary` field:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (
    e_id NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    f_name VARCHAR(20),
    salary NUMBER(37),
    dept_name VARCHAR(10)
);
```

For reference, the wealthiest people in the world earn on the order of 1 billion per year, so `NUMBER(9)` would probably be sufficient for your salary field.